# oracle sql sorting clarification

Tags: sql, oracle, sorting

Question:

I want to display Ename from scott.emp table such that all the enames with starting with letter 'S' 
should come first and all other enames should be sorted in alphabetical order.

Comment: Why did you remove your sample data ?

Answer (score 2):

Add this `ORDER BY` to your query :

```
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN ENAME LIKE 'S%' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END) DESC
       , ENAME DESC
```

Comment: That won't sort the non-S% enames in alphabetical order.  They'll come after the S% `ename` values but in an arbitrary order.  You could add `ename` as a secondary sort.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT ename
  FROM scott.emp
 ORDER BY (CASE WHEN ename LIKE 'S%'
                THEN 'A'
                ELSE ename
            END)
```